# Date and Time issue while signing pdf document using Itext sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

i have document signer and the same we are using for pdf sign electronically using itext sharp

1. I have server location @ north USA
2. when we are using defult date and time then pdf is generated with valid signature
3. when I am converting / setting different date time with conversion then pdf is generated with In valid signature

my sample code is as below  (Working )

```
        public void Sign(string DSCFileNameWithPath, string keyPassword, string SoruceDocument, string DesitinationDocument, Cert mycert, string SigReason, string SigContact, string SigLocation, string AppprovedBy, bool visible)
        {
            string logfile = Path.GetDirectoryName(SoruceDocument) + "\\WriteText.txt";

            try
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SoruceDocument);
                PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(DesitinationDocument, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, true);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(logfile, "st created" + "\n");
                st.MoreInfo = HashtableToDictionary(metadata.getMetaData());
                st.XmpMetadata = metadata.getStreamedMetaData();
                PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "DSCFileNameWithPath" + DSCFileNameWithPath + "\n");
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "SoruceDocument" + SoruceDocument + "\n");
                //System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "SoruceDocument" + SoruceDocument + "\n");

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Cert Initialization " + "\n");

                X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(DSCFileNameWithPath, keyPassword);
                IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1");

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Cert reading started " + "\n");

                Stream fs = File.OpenRead(DSCFileNameWithPath);
                Stream privateKeyStream = fs;

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Cert reading finished " + "\n");

                Pkcs12Store pk12 = new Pkcs12Store(privateKeyStream, keyPassword.ToCharArray());
                privateKeyStream.Dispose();

                string alias = null;
                foreach (string tAlias in pk12.Aliases)
                {
                    if (pk12.IsKeyEntry(tAlias))
                    {
                        alias = tAlias; break;
                    }
                }
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "pk12 finished " + "\n");

                var pk = pk12.GetKey(alias).Key;

                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Pk ceated.");

                X509CertificateEntry[] ce = pk12.GetCertificateChain(alias);
                Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain;
                chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[ce.Length];
                for (int k = 0; k < ce.Length; ++k)
                {
                    chain[k] = ce[k].Certificate;
                }
                sap.Reason = SigReason;
                sap.Contact = AppprovedBy;
                sap.Location = SigLocation;
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Got certifcate.");
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Singer started .");
                sap.Acro6Layers = false;
                sap.Layer4Text = PdfSignatureAppearance.questionMark;
                sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(580, 100, 450, 150), 1, null);
                MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
                st.Close();
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Sign finished.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Error occured" + ex + ex.Message + ex.InnerException + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

my sample code is as below  (not Working )

```
        public void Sign(string DSCFileNameWithPath, string keyPassword, string SoruceDocument, string DesitinationDocument, Cert mycert, string SigReason, string SigContact, string SigLocation, string AppprovedBy, bool visible)
        {
            string logfile = Path.GetDirectoryName(SoruceDocument) + "\\WriteText.txt";

            try
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SoruceDocument);
                PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(DesitinationDocument, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, true);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(logfile, "st created" + "\n");
                st.MoreInfo = HashtableToDictionary(metadata.getMetaData());
                st.XmpMetadata = metadata.getStreamedMetaData();
                PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "DSCFileNameWithPath" + DSCFileNameWithPath + "\n");
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "SoruceDocument" + SoruceDocument + "\n");
                //System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "SoruceDocument" + SoruceDocument + "\n");

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Cert Initialization " + "\n");

                X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(DSCFileNameWithPath, keyPassword);
                IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1");

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Cert reading started " + "\n");

                Stream fs = File.OpenRead(DSCFileNameWithPath);
                Stream privateKeyStream = fs;

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Cert reading finished " + "\n");

                Pkcs12Store pk12 = new Pkcs12Store(privateKeyStream, keyPassword.ToCharArray());
                privateKeyStream.Dispose();

                string alias = null;
                foreach (string tAlias in pk12.Aliases)
                {
                    if (pk12.IsKeyEntry(tAlias))
                    {
                        alias = tAlias; break;
                    }
                }
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logfile, "pk12 finished " + "\n");

                var pk = pk12.GetKey(alias).Key;

                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Pk ceated.");

                X509CertificateEntry[] ce = pk12.GetCertificateChain(alias);
                Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain;
                chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[ce.Length];
                for (int k = 0; k < ce.Length; ++k)
                {
                    chain[k] = ce[k].Certificate;
                }
                sap.SignDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(A_Common_Objects.TimeZone));
                sap.Reason = SigReason;
                sap.Contact = AppprovedBy;
                sap.Location = SigLocation;
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Got certifcate.");
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Singer started .");
                sap.Acro6Layers = false;
                sap.Layer4Text = PdfSignatureAppearance.questionMark;
                sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(580, 100, 450, 150), 1, null);
                MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
                st.Close();
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Sign finished.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, "Error occured" + ex + ex.Message + ex.InnerException + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

---------------------Code differance -------------------------
sap.SignDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(A_Common_Objects.TimeZone));

what is should do in this case to get rectifed code which is not working

Comment: There's a lot of code there and I doubt that most of it is relevant. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question accordingly. We are all volunteers so the less time we have to spend wading through irrelevant code to work out what's relevant, the more likely you'll get the help you want.

Comment: what does the date look like?  Is it text of DateTime?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You say the second piece of code creates an invalid signature. In which way is it invalid?

Comment: below line creates issue 

  sap.SignDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(A_Common_Objects.TimeZone));